# Why is DNS resolution so slow using full DHCP on my Ubuntu 20.10 laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, display-resolution

Lately I have noticed that if I set my wi-fi connection to full DHCP getting DNS from the router resolution of many addresses are very slow. There's up to a five second delay before the web page is resolved and loaded. If I set the same DNS as used on the router manually in the connection settings, DNS performs as I'm used to. Not all sites are affected by this. Many are instant as before but many are also slow to resolve. This only happens on my Ubuntu 20.10 laptop, not on Windows and not on my phone.

Comment: DNS resolution being slow would be based on the DNS settings you're getting from DHCP - if that's assigning DNS servers that're dead or nonresponsive, then that's your core issue.  Run `resolvectl status` when using full DHCP and include the output please as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to change the DNS servers set on the router which are the ones used  in my DHCP wi-fi connection. The issue is that this intermittent delays only happen on my Ubuntu 20.10 computer. Other devices like my phone does not have these delays using the same DNS servers through DHCP.

Comment: I've also discovered this issue after migration to Ubuntu 20.10.